# Question about building react state with fetch() and .then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have an issue when I tried to fetch a json file and build the react state.

```js
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            cards: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/583950/resource/card_set_1.3E50A21FB5DAFC5864FE5DE99E0EC84E4B3F00DB.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(cardsets => this.setState({
                cards: cardsets.card_set.card_list
            }))
    }
```

Above is the code I finished. It's working. So at this point I want to let my `this.state.cards[i]` object have a name 'color', and the value would be based on `this.state.cards[i].is_blue` or `this.state.cards[i].is_red` etc (these are just from the json file).

I'm wondering how could I do this. Please help me I'm very new to react.

Comment: So, how many `is_[color]` in total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `map` to the wanted format before setting it to the state:

```
this.setState({
 cards: cardsets.card_set.card_list.map(({ is_red, is_blue, ...rest }) => ({ 
   color: (is_red && "red") || (is_blue && "blue") || "black",
   ...rest
  })),
});
```

Then you can access `cards[i].color` while rendering.

Or you just extract the color directly when rendering:

```
 render() {
  const { cards } = this.state;

  return cards.map(card => {
   const { is_blue, is_red } = card;
   const color = (is_red && "red") || (is_blue && "blue") || "black";

   return <div style={{ color }} >Card</div>;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your second `then` with a `map`:

```
.then(cardsets => this.setState({ cards: cardsets.card_set.card_list.map(card => card.color = card.is_red ? "red" : "blue")}));
```